# What does "CUTTING THROUGH THE HYPE" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I checked many dictionaries but could not find the answer. I think it is not an idiom. How can we explain this phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cut through [something] is a figurative use. Imagine using a machete to **cut** a pathway **through** some bushes.

Hype - you can find the meaning in any good dictionary.

To cut through the hype = to dispense with or throw away the extravagant or intensive publicity or promotion.

Answer (score 1):

*Cut through* is a phrasal verb. It means [“to get quickly and directly through or past (something that blocks one or slows one down)”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut%20through).

The hype needs to be inferred from the context (which, unfortunately, you haven’t provided). It can mean [“publicity or promotion” (noun 2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hype), which is, probably, uncalled-for, unwelcome.

It also has a literal meaning: to puncture, penetrate.

Comment: Many thanks.
You are right, I should have given the context, as well. Below is the context:

"In particular, it will explore the following:

--- Cutting through the hype: Blockchain origins
--- Cryptocurrencies: What are they and how do they work?
--- Why are there so many cryptocurrencies and how can we trade them effectively?"